# How to insert a custom view inside another customview using addview

Tags: android

I know that this question has been answered before but the replies doesn't help me much.

I have two custom views, one that I need to insert a LinearLayout and this works, but I have another one that I need to insert and from customview to customview I don't understand what is the correct approach. I have a project to complete, a memory game, the first customview is a tablerow, and the second one will be an imageview, in order to be able to change the content dynamically. Here's my code for the first custom view.

```
package com.example.memorymind;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import com.example.game.Card;
import com.example.game.Game;
import com.example.game.Skin;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.opengl.Visibility;
import android.text.method.HideReturnsTransformationMethod;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class ViewGrid extends LinearLayout{

class Layout {

    public Layout() {
        imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        imageView4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    }
    ImageView imageView1, imageView2, imageView3, imageView4;
}
Layout l;
int Status = 0;

public ViewGrid(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_grid, this);


    l = new Layout(); setupSkin(); setupGame();onClick(); 

}
void cardSkin(int skin) {
    l.imageView1.setImageResource(skin);

    l.imageView2.setImageResource(skin);

    l.imageView3.setImageResource(skin);

    l.imageView4.setImageResource(skin);

}
void setupSkin() {
    switch (MainActivity.skin) {
    case Skin.android:
        cardSkin(Skin.android);
        break;
    case Skin.question:
        cardSkin(Skin.question);
        break;
    case Skin.disney:
        cardSkin(Skin.disney);
        break;
    }
}
void setupGame() {
    switch (MainActivity.game) {
    case Game.numbers:

        break;
    case Game.animals:

        break;
    case Game.disney:
        loadGameDisney();
        break;
    }
}
void loadGameDisney() {
    Card[] disney = new Card[] {
        new Card(R.drawable.disney_mickey), 
        new Card(R.drawable.disney_dingo),
        new Card(R.drawable.disney_donald),
        new Card(R.drawable.disney_minnie),
        new Card(R.drawable.disney_plutot), 
        new Card(R.drawable.disney_tigroux),
        new Card(R.drawable.disney_pinocchio),
        new Card(R.drawable.disney_mufasa)
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < disney.length; i++) {
        l.imageView1.setBackgroundResource(disney[0].Image);
        l.imageView2.setBackgroundResource(disney[4].Image);
        l.imageView3.setBackgroundResource(disney[2].Image);
        l.imageView4.setBackgroundResource(disney[3].Image);

    }
}
void onClick() {
    l.imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            if (Status == 0) {
                l.imageView1.setImageResource(INVISIBLE);
                loadGameDisney();
                Status = 1;
            }else{
                resetBackground(l.imageView1);
                Status = 0;
            }
        }
    });
}
void resetBackground(ImageView object) {
    object.setImageResource(MainActivity.skin);
}
}
```

Basically right now, I put my imageviews manually into my customview but I would like to create another customview with only a imageview that I can add to my first customview. The same way I do it in this code.

```
void addRow() {
    LinearLayout table = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutMain);
    ViewGrid row = new ViewGrid(this, null);
    table.addView(row);
}
```

The second customview will be called ViewCard for example. 
Thanks for your help